# add two lists then sort = None(?)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Second list squared each item on list, xs. Running the code below, python gives me 'None'

```
xs = [12, 10, 32, 3, 66, 17, 42, 99, 20]
a = [b**2 for b in xs]
c = (a + xs).sort()
print(c, end=', ')
```

Same list but different code--

```
xs = [12, 10, 32, 3, 66, 17, 42, 99, 20]
a = [b**2 for b in xs]
c = a + xs
c.sort()
print(c, end=', ')
```

...python gives me my list(c), all sorted. I don't get it. Or is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally speaking, anything that operates on something *in-place* will return `None`, by convention. (This convention is not necessarily always followed, however.)  `somelist.sort()` will sort the list in-place.

If you'd rather have a sorted *copy*, you can just call `c = sorted(a + xs)`.  `sorted` operates on a copy of the original, and therefore returns the copy.

There's a much more through explanation here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/

Comment: @OP: Functions that `pass` or simply `return` are equivalent to `return None`. The output from all function calls in python are assignable even if you don't think they are returning anything at all. `list.sort` returns None.

Answer (score 4):

You use generator expressions and itertools to reduce the amount of temporary storage like this

```
>>> import itertools
>>> xs = [12, 10, 32, 3, 66, 17, 42, 99, 20]
>>> a = (b**2 for b in xs)
>>> c = sorted(itertools.chain(a, xs))
>>> c
[3, 9, 10, 12, 17, 20, 32, 42, 66, 99, 100, 144, 289, 400, 1024, 1764, 4356, 9801]
```